# How to properly use imap_mail_compose

Tags: php, email, imap

i'm currently programming a webmail script and I don't know how to properly use the imap_mail_compose function.

The documentations and examples are not very explicit and there is no examples on google.

My question is : how should i use properly this function with the data i obtain from my form (to,cc,bcc,subject,content,attachements) ? Then how to send this message : imap_mail or mail ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you looked at [the manual page for `imap_mail_compose`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mail-compose.php)?  Which parts do you need help with?

Answer (score -1):

Consider looking at the likes of PHPMailer by Worx Tech. Used it a few times and it's proven very useful in the past proving easy to use and stable.

Project site (sourceforge) (PHP 5.x.x): http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/ and project site google code: http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

The basic tutorial can be found by visiting the PHPMailer page searching 'PHPMailer' in Google and goto Products > PHPMailer > Support - Tutorial. Don't let the site put you off, the classes themselves are excellent.

Comment: Updated link to [PHPMailer on GitHub](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).